# Can I have nested User Controls in ASPnet mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls

How would I go about this?

EDIT: USER CONTROL WITHIN USER CONTROL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use nested calls to [`Html.RenderPartial`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/08/partial-renderi.html).

i.e. Have Html.RenderPartial in your page1.aspx view to render your usercontrol1.ascx view

that contains another Html.RenderPartial call to render usercontrol2.ascx

Answer (score 1):

You want to look up Partial Views

here is a link to get you started http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/08/partial-renderi.html